# How can I create an automatic grid layout with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have a few images which all have the same height but different widths. I would like to arrange them inside a .container in such a way that they automatically form rows and columns.
Basically, fill the row with images until theres no more space. Then go to the next row.
Is there a way to do this in Bootstrap?